# Unable to restore iPhone 5 after it dropped

Tags: iphone, ios

I have dropped my iPhone 5 last night and since then its either been flashing the apple logo on and off or just stuck in recovery mode. I have tried restoring it, but I just get error 21 or error 2002. I have tried using reboots, holding the home button and the on/off button and nothing seem to work.

How can I restore the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 21 indicates issues with the power source/battery, error 2002 usually is a connection problem. Given the fall your phone did, it's a safe guess that something broke or got disconnected on the inside.

It's probably best to go to your nearest Apple Retail Store (if this is an option), your vendor or a local iPhone repair shop. If you are used to fixing electronic devices yourself, you may also find instructions on [ifixit.com](http://ifixit.com/) (search for the error number).

Comment: thankyou, do you know what i would be looking for on the ifixit.com? and its not possible to get to the apple retail store, what would the repair shops be able to do? as i need to get it fixed as soon as possible

Comment: hi just tried to restore it again and now its showing error -18? what does that mean?

Comment: http://www.stepbystep.com/how-to-fix-iphone-error-18-overview-43954/, but I really think you should have somebody look at the hardware of your phone.

Comment: thankyou, it restored the screen came up and when i went to unlock it.. it went back off and start flashing the appple logo again?

Comment: buts letting me restore it again but first after it restore its said theres an update do i need that update?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing the state your phone is in. But if it keeps re-displaying the Apple logo, it's not only a software problem.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If you get different error messages and repeated crashes even after a full restore, you may still be facing a hardware problem and need somebody to have a look at it.

Comment: think i need to have a look as its just continuing to flash the apple sign but thankyou for your help.